# I want to count the number of windows open and close them one by one using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner and I am using python and selenium for automation. so, Please solve the below question in python-selenium.

Q. Suppose n number of windows are open. I want to count the number of windows open and print them. Then close all the windows one by one.

Here is what I have written:

```
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Flights').click()
multi_window = driver.window_handles
length = len(multi_window)
print("Number of window open: ", length)
```

How do I close the windows one by one?

Comment: Can you update the question with what exactly you mean by _`print them`_ as in `count the number of windows open and print them`

Comment: Yes. It will count the number of windows open and print them.                 
E.g: If 3 windows are open, it will print ("window open 3") and then close all three windows one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to switch to each window one by one and close them:

```
for window in multi_window:
    driver.switch_to.window(window)
    driver.close()
```

Note that this will close **all opened windows**. If you want to stay on initial window:

```
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in")
current = driver.current_window_handle

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Flights').click()
multi_window = driver.window_handles

for window in multi_window:
    if window != current:
        driver.switch_to.window(window)
        driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(current)
```

Comment: Thank you Andersson. I'll try this out and share my results.

Comment: Welcome! You can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem